# How can i change the file codification in visual studio 2012?

Tags: file, visual-studio-2012

I want to change the file codification in visual studio 2012, anyone know how?
Is there any extension that can do this automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "file codification"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to change a character encoding for certain files. In this case you need to use "Advanced save options" in the "Save File as" dialog from "File" menu. You can read more about encodings in VS2012 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx